# sequence limit - proof with definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

so I have to prove the existence of the following limit with the definition of a sequence limit:
$$\lim_{x = \infty }  \frac{1}{n+1} = 0 $$
the thing is that I'm a bit struggling with understanding the way of proof. I seem to understand the logic behind the epsilon and $n \geqslant N $ definition both graphically and notionally, however am not really sure in which relation N and epsilon are.

according to the definition the following satisfies:
$$\mid \frac{1}{n+1} - 0 \mid < \varepsilon  $$
As I saw in other problems one should be able sometimes to "pick" an epsilon or an N value, so that it would make sense and create a relation between the two, but don't know how to proceed.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: did you mean $n\to\infty$ where you typed $x=\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

For all $\epsilon>0$, you have to find an index $N=N(\epsilon)$ such that  $n \geq N \implies \left|\frac{1}{n+1}-0\right| < \epsilon$. We now show this.

Fix an $\epsilon > 0$. Let $N$ be so large that $1/N < \epsilon$ (Archimedian property). If $n \geq N$, then

$$\left|\frac{1}{n+1}-0\right|= \frac{1}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$$

Since $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, we may conclude.

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't pick the $\varepsilon$ value, but you can pick $N$ to be as large as you want.  With these, it's sometimes best to work backwards, meaning start with what you want, and figure out what you need.  So we want

$$ \frac{1}{n+1}<\varepsilon. $$

By some algebra that just means that we want $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}<n+1$.  So choosing $N$ large enough such that $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}<N+1$, then for all $n \geq N$ we get the desired result.

Comment: So the logic is that from the n and N inequality one can imply the absolut value inequality with epsilon

Comment: And by working backwards you mean that one could start with the inequality of epsilon then conclude the n out of it and imply about N. How should one write it backwards then? I mean, after one did that and wants to go from the N to the epsilon

Comment: Usually you want to do a bit of scratch work beforehand.  So to the side we might start with what we did, but when we start the actual proof we would say "Let $\varepsilon>0$, and choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-1<N$."

We would then show that for all $n \geq N$ we have $\left| \frac{1}{n+1} \right|<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Everything come from definition:
as $\varepsilon$ is on left hand of $N$ and $N$ is under $\exists$ existence quantifier, then this means that $N$ depend on $\varepsilon$: $N = N (\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Of course constructive critique is welcome. But anyway down voting of correct answer seems little strange.

Comment: Seems like all our answers were downvoted. I upvoted the other answers to undo this :)

Comment: @ε-δ . Thank you - seems it is in great fashion to down vote silently.